# Facebook login issue with Codename one

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-login, codenameone

I am working with Facebook api in Codename one, In the initial stage it works fine, but now when I am clicking on login button it display loading but after completion it will not redirect to the Facebook login page And there is no any error while loading and also after completion.[image]

**Following is my code:**

```
public class FacebookDemo {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;
    Form facebook;
    Toolbar tb;
    Image user;
    Label userLabel;
    Label username;
    Login loginfb;
    String clientId = "158093724691158";
    String redirectURI = "http://www.codenameone.com/";
    String clientSecret = "4f5b275ae702f7b6fde9bc50bfe3b5e3";

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        try{
        Splash spl = new Splash();
        spl.show();

        new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                facebook.show();
            }
        } , 4000);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       facebook = new Form("Facebook", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        tb = new Toolbar();
        facebook.setToolbar(tb);

       user = theme.getImage("user.png");
        userLabel = new Label(user);
        username = new Label("Visitor");
        Button login = new Button("Login with Facebook");
        Button linked = new Button("Login with LinkedIn");
        //linked.setUIID("linkedButton");

        linked.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                          Oauth2 auth2 = new Oauth2("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code", 
                "81lq3qpacjvkcu", 
                "https://www.codenameone.com","r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress","https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken","vzwWfamZ3IUQsJQL");
        Oauth2.setBackToParent(true);
        auth2.showAuthentication(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getSource() instanceof String) {
                    String token = (String) evt.getSource();
                    String expires = Oauth2.getExpires();

                    System.out.println("Token=" +token + "Expires in " +expires );

                } else {
                    Exception err = (Exception) evt.getSource();
                    err.printStackTrace();
                    Dialog.show("Error", "An error occurred while logging in: " + err, "OK", null);
                }
            }
        });

       }
        });

        login.addActionListener((evt) -> {
            Login fb = FacebookConnect.getInstance();
                fb.setClientId(clientId);
                fb.setRedirectURI(redirectURI);
                fb.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
                loginfb = fb;
                fb.setCallback(new LoginListener(LoginListener.FACEBOOK));
                if(!fb.isUserLoggedIn()){
                    fb.doLogin();
                }else{
                    showFacebookUser(fb.getAccessToken().getToken());
                }
        });



        Container container1 = BoxLayout.encloseY(userLabel,username);
        container1.setUIID("container1");
        tb.addComponentToSideMenu(container1);
        tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Home", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
         tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Shop by Category", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ADD_SHOPPING_CART, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
          tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Todays Deals", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_LOCAL_OFFER, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
           tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Your Orders", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_BOOKMARK_BORDER, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
            tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Your Wish List", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_LIST, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
             tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Your Account", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ACCOUNT_BOX, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
              tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Gift Cards", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_CARD_GIFTCARD, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
               tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Setting", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {
        });
                tb.addCommandToSideMenu("Logout", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_BACKSPACE, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand")), (evt) -> {

//                    if(loginfb.isUserLoggedIn()){
//                       
//            loginfb.doLogout();  
//        loginfb.setAccessToken(null);
//         Preferences.delete(FacebookDemo.this.getClass().getName() + "Token");
//          user = theme.getImage("user.png");
//        userLabel = new Label(user);
//        username = new Label("Visitor");
//        Dialog.show("Log out", "User successfully logged out!", "OK","");
//        }
//                    else{
//                        Dialog.show("Log out", "User already logged out!", "OK","");
//                            }
        });


        Tabs tab = new Tabs();
        Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab");
        FontImage icon1 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_VPN_KEY, s);
        FontImage icon2 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS, s);
        FontImage icon3 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ACCOUNT_BOX, s);

        Container container11 = BoxLayout.encloseY(login,linked);
Container container12 = BoxLayout.encloseY(new SpanLabel("Some text directly in the tab2"));
Container container13 = BoxLayout.encloseY(new SpanLabel("Some text directly in the tab3"));

        tab.addTab("Log In",icon1,container11 );
        tab.addTab("Setting",icon2, container12 );
        tab.addTab("User Profile",icon3, container13);

        facebook.add(tab);
    }

    private void showFacebookUser(String token){
       ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest(){
           @Override
           protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
              JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

                Map<String, Object> parsed = parser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));


              String email = (String) parsed.get("email");
               String name = (String) parsed.get("name");
                String first_name = (String) parsed.get("first_name");
                String last_name = (String) parsed.get("last_name");
                  String gender = (String) parsed.get("gender");
                String image = (String) ((Map) ((Map) parsed.get("picture")).get("data")).get("url").toString();

                  Log.p("First NAme : " + first_name);
                Log.p("Last Name : " + last_name);
       Log.p("Email : " + email);
        Log.p("Full Name : " + name);
          Log.p("Gender : " + gender);
             Log.p("Picture : " +image);
         username.setText(name);
        userLabel.setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage((EncodedImage) user, "Small_"+image, image, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE));     

           }           
       };
       req.setPost(false);
        req.setUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me");
        req.addArgumentNoEncoding("access_token", token); //this statement is used to patch access token with url
        req.addArgumentNoEncoding("fields", "email,name,first_name,last_name,gender,picture.width(512).height(512),feed{name,full_picture,message,story}");
        //above statement is used to provide permission through url so server send data with respect ot permissions.
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(req);
    }


    public class LoginListener extends LoginCallback {

        public static final int FACEBOOK = 0;

        private int loginType;

        public LoginListener(int loginType) {
            this.loginType = loginType;
        }

        public void loginSuccessful() {

            try {
                AccessToken token = loginfb.getAccessToken();
                if (loginType == FACEBOOK) {
                    showFacebookUser(token.getToken());
                } 

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
            Dialog.show("Login Failed", errorMessage, "Ok", null);
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: It's possible you are authorized already. Do you get a token callback or not? Are loginSuccessful/failed invoked?

Comment: No, I am not already logged in and if it is so then the user information display on screen but it is not display and after some clicks or after terminating app login window appear.

Comment: Is this only on the simulator, only on the device or both? Do you see any output in the console if the former?

Comment: In simulator at the time of loading it takes few seconds and then stop loading But in physical device it display loading until you don't terminating the application.

Comment: These can be tough issues to debug.  Try to narrow down exactly in your code how far it reaches before it stalls.  Check the network monitor in simulator to see if it offers any clues.  Add some logging/break points in all callbacks to see where it reaches.

Comment: Now in a simulator when I am clicking on login button three times, then it will redirect to Facebook login screen.